# How can I proxy game traffic (UDP and TCP) through a remote Ubuntu server?

Tags: games, proxy

I want to run a game client on my windows machine, but route the traffic through an Ubuntu server located in another country. I know this will likely hurt latency, but that's not the main concern here.

What software should I install and how should I configure it on the remote Ubuntu server to make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do it at the host level with vpn clients, I would do it at the network level with an in-line fix...that way your proxying can't be detected by the client software.

So the reference to openvpn is partially correct.  I would, however, use openswan if you are going to support more than two users in the future.

Look into site to site vpns with openswan and you should be able to work out exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

VPN. Notably OpenVPN.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openvpn.html